# Trouble with remote connection - Access denied

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to connect to a remote machine with PowerShell from my machine and execute a script on the remote machine. My machine (Windows 10) and the remote machine (Windows Server 2008 R2) are on the same network but not in the same domain. Here's what I did:

I enabled WinRM and configured it to allow unencrypted and allow basic authentication on both my machine and the remote. The output of `winrm g winrm/config`:

- On my machine:
  [image]
- On the remote machine:
  [image]

The command is (`Enter-PSSession`):

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "StrongPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("remotemachine\user",$secpasswd)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName remotemachine -Credential $credentials -Authentication Basic
```

The error is:

```
Enter-PSSession : La connexion au serveur distant remotemachine a échoué avec
le message d’erreur suivant : Accès refusé. Pour plus d'informations, voir la
rubrique d'aide about_Remote_Troubleshooting.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName remotemachine -Credential $credentials ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (remotemachine:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Which translates to:

> The connection to the remote server remotemachine failed with the following error message: Access denied. For more information, see the help topic about_Remote_Troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Fourat, are you an administrator on the remote machine?

Comment: @Neossian yes the user `remotemachine\user` has administrator rights on remote machine.

Comment: What if you do not mention the auth type. Only use this: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName remotemachine -Credential $credentials`

Comment: @RohinSidharth Oddly it works, can you tell why it doesn't work even when Basic Auth is actived ?

Comment: I am not an expert but I think basic authentication requires a different format of credential.

Comment: @RohinSidharth I didn't find any object other than `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` that can be used for authentifaction. Meanwhile, please post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: actually interested in this, but im not sure if this one is correct. "*Basic authentication sends a Base64-encoded string that contains a user name and password for the client. Base64 is not a form of encryption and should be considered the same as sending the user name and password in clear text. If a resource needs to be protected, strongly consider using an authentication scheme other than basic authentication.*"
**source**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication

Comment: @CarlArdiente I tried encoding to Base64 but it prompts me the authentication window with the username encoded and I don't think what's in the article applies in powershell since the article is about WCF (btw authentication described in the article is for HTTP headers).